# Where's the difference of those two same 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is a little piece of code:

```
from random import randint
code = "%d%d%d " % (randint(1, 9), randint(1, 9), randint(1, 9))
print(code)
guess = input("[keypad]> ")
print(guess == code)
```

When I input the same number as the printed representation of `code`, the last line of this snippet will print `False`.

Why does this happen? Aren't `guess` and `code` equal string values?

Comment: @tobias_k: I guess that's what they actually want, though I may have guessed wrong... Never mind.

Comment: @vaultah Did not say it's wrong, just that it's different. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put a *space* at the end of your random-generated `code` value:

```
code = "%d%d%d " % (randint(1, 9), randint(1, 9), randint(1, 9))
#             ^
```

That space is *significant*; most people won't see the space and not enter it at the prompt:

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> code = "%d%d%d " % (randint(1, 9), randint(1, 9), randint(1, 9))
>>> code
'634 '
>>> '634' == code
False
>>> '634 ' == code
True
```

Either remove that extra space, or make sure you enter the space at the prompt:

```
>>> guess = input("[keypad]> ")
[keypad]> 634
>>> guess  # note the extra space I entered!
'634 '
>>> guess == code
True
```

Answer (score -3):

You tagged your question `python-3.x`, so this may not be your problem, but your program has no *obvious* Python-3-isms in it, so I'm going to mention it anyway for the benefit of future readers who may not notice the tags.

In Python 2, `input` reads a line *and evaluates it as Python code*.  This is almost never what you want.  In this case, it means that any number you type will be converted from a string to an actual number, and strings never compare equal to numbers.  It also means that someone can cheat by typing the word "code" at the prompt.

Instead, use either `raw_input` or `sys.stdin.readline`.

(In Python 3, `input` does what `raw_input` used to do.)